# Converting objects to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following variable

```
my_res = RecognizeEntitiesResult(id=0, entities=[
    CategorizedEntity(text=50,000, category=Quantity, subcategory=Number, offset=10, length=6, confidence_score=0.8), 
    CategorizedEntity(text=infectious, category=Skill, subcategory=None, offset=29, length=10, confidence_score=0.8)], 
    warnings=[], statistics=None, is_error=False)
```

I want to have a Dataframe where each `CategorizedEntity` is a row, and the column for each row is the `text`, the `category`, and the `confidence_score`.

I tried the below, but with no success.

```
[x.as_dict() for x in my_res]
```

I could of course manually go through each CategorizedEntity and create a new row one by one but that doesnt seem very Pandas/Python-ic.

Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the most simple way to map data to dictionary would be:

```
from azure.ai.textanalytics import RecognizeEntitiesResult
from azure.ai.textanalytics import CategorizedEntity
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

d = defaultdict(list)

my_res = RecognizeEntitiesResult(id=0, entities=[
    CategorizedEntity(text='50,000', category='Quantity', subcategory='Number', offset=10, length=6, confidence_score=0.8), 
    CategorizedEntity(text='infectious', category='Skill', subcategory=None, offset=29, length=10, confidence_score=0.8)], 
    warnings=[], statistics=None, is_error=False)

for e in my_res.entities:
  for k, v in e.items():
    if (k in ['text', 'category', 'confidence_score']):
      d[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.head()
```